# animation-play-state paused not working ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations

I've encountered a bug on ie-edge while using css animation.

HTML:

```
<div class="teaser-large image-loaded>
   <img src="level3Brand-1.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS3:

```
teaser-large {
   opacity: 0;
   animation: fadeLeft 700ms ease-in-out;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
image-loaded {
   -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
   animation-play-state: paused; 
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In div the class definition not closed with double quotes, class names in CSS not starting with a dot, opacity 0 for div, fadeLeft keyframes not defined. How do you expect this to visualize anything in any browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `.` in the `.class`name defenition in CSS. Also note that some browser require prefixes for the CSS properties in order to work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation#Browser_compatibility

```css
.teaser-large {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation: fadeLeft 700ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: fadeLeft 700ms ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: fadeLeft 700ms ease-in-out;
  animation: fadeLeft 700ms ease-in-out;
  
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.image-loaded {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: paused;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused; 
}
```

```html
<div class="teaser-large image-loaded">
  <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/08/19/10/16/nature-3616194_960_720.jpg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
teaser-large {
   opacity: 0;
   animation: fadeLeft 700ms ease-in-out;
   animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   -webkit-animation: fadeLeft 700ms ease-in-out;
   -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

Opera: `-o-animation`...
Firefox: `-moz-animation`...